# How to define variable derived from a target built with ExternalProject_add in cmake?

Tags: cmake, external-project

You can get a property of a CMake target that was built using `ExternalProject_add` using something like this:

```
ExternalProject_Get_property(zipper SOURCE_DIR)
message("Source dir of myExtProj = ${SOURCE_DIR}")
```

How would I save this to another variable, i.e. not `SOURCE_DIR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `${SOURCE_DIR}` to print its value, you can use it set another variable, using the [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-normal-variable) command:

```
ExternalProject_Get_property(zipper SOURCE_DIR)
message("Source dir of myExtProj = ${SOURCE_DIR}")

# Set the variable zipper_SOURCE_DIR.
set(zipper_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
```